# How do you aggregate social activity using Postgres?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, aggregate

In this app I have users, posts, and groups. Users post to groups, of which many users can be a part of.

I'm trying to aggregate all this into a feed where if a multiple groups you're part of have a post made to them (in consecutive order, with no activity in between) it groups it into 1. So you'd see "Posted in 5 groups" instead of the post 5 times in your activity feed.

[Example of the schema & desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp7IP.png)

How would you do this with Postgres queries? Imagine thousands of posts in various orders, and you only want the newsfeed to show related activities that are right next to each other

Also I'm using node js for backend if there's any libraries to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The expected result looks clear, but the origin data is not there yet. For example, about 101, 102, etc.